# Evaluating $\lim\limits _{x \to\infty} \frac{2^{1/x}}{x\left(2^{1/x} -1\right)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Calculate the limit

$$\lim\limits _{x \to\infty} \frac{2^{1/x}}{x\left(2^{1/x} -1\right)}$$

So this is just part 2) of a question where in the end I got to evaluate the integral of $2^x$ between [0,1] by the definion.

I reached this expression for the upper sum and I know that if this lim is equal to the lower sum the function is integrable. I am just stuck on the limit part. I tried out L'Hospital's rule, but it gives me an even more complex expression than what I started with; so, I know this is not the direction, but I am not sure about how to evaluate it in a different way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use $e^{x^{-1}\ln2}-1\sim x^{-1}\ln2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting

$$2^{\frac{1}{x}}=t,$$

from which

$$x=\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(t)}.$$

The limit becomes:

$$\lim\limits _{x \to ∞} \frac{2^{1/x}}{x(2^{1/x} -1)}=\lim\limits _{t \to 1} \frac{t \ln(t)}{(t-1) \ln(2)},$$

applying L'Hospital's rule:

$$=\lim\limits _{t \to 1} \frac{\ln(t)+1}{\ln(2)}=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}.$$

Comment: Many thanks @Gary for giving a more elegant look to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\lim\limits _{x \to \infty} \frac{2^{1/x}}{x({2^{1/x} -1)}}=\lim\limits _{y \to 0} \frac{y\,2^y }{2^y-1}=\frac 1{\log(2)}\lim\limits _{y \to 0} \frac{y\log(2)\,2^y }{2^y-1}$$

Now using $2^y=e^{y\log(2)}$
$$t=y\log(2) \implies A=\frac 1{\log(2)}\lim\limits _{t \to 0}\frac{ t\,e^t}{e^t-1}$$

Now, use Taylor series or equivalents.

Comment: Why do think Taylor series would be available to someone working on a Riemann sum?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. I was answering the question as written in title.

Comment: The title is just that. The actual question is in the question body.